# how to download a directory from FTP server in android

Tags: java, android

I successfully downloaded single file from FTP server to my SD card by giving URL.But i'm unable to download a folder which contains 30 files(.jpg,.flv,etc., may be have another folder inside folder) from FTP server.so please help me some code, how to download an entire folder from FTP server to SD card. Thanks in advance!!

**HERE IS THE CODE FOR SINGLE FILE DOWNLOAD**:

```
public boolean downloadFTP(String srcFilePath, String desFilePath) {
    boolean status = false;
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        String ipaddr = "XX.XX.XX.XX";
        String uname = "XXXXXX";
        String pass = "XXXXXX";

        client.connect(ipaddr, 21);
        client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        boolean login = client.login(uname, pass);
        if (login) {
            Log.e("downloadFTP login : ", "Success");
            FileOutputStream desFileStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    desFilePath);
            Log.e("downloadFTP login : ", "FileOutputStream");
            status = client.retrieveFile(srcFilePath, desFileStream);
            Log.e("downloadFTP status : ", "" + status);
            desFileStream.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR downloadFTP : ", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to list the files and manage the download queue bu yourself.